# jquery menu hovering

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseevent

i have a menu that when i mouse over a div it will show and on mouse out it will fade out. the problem is that if you roll over any of the menu's children the menu will disappear(because technically if you're over one of the children then you're not over the parent) is there a way  so that rolling over the children will not count as a mouseout? here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/32bLg/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very simple problem most people tend to massively overcomplicate with timers and special case checks. The easy solution is via markup. Place both hover target and the menu under the same parent, and track hover on the parent. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/32bLg/14/). 
You may also want to use `hoverIntent` jQuery plugin to avoid false hover events.

A UX note: fade animations lasting over 500ms are just rude. Please don't do that.

Comment: most excellent. just like in life the simplest answer usually is the correct one. also the 500ms was just for testing, thats too quick for most people to notice anyway...thanks dude.

Comment: I am having some problem when I try to mouse in and out of the menu .. 'now before fadeOut'.. mouse in examplePic and mouse out now.. and again mouse in messes up the animation.

Comment: @SKS yes, using regular `hover` event + long animations would do that. Switch to `hoverIntent` and short animations and you would not see that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/32bLg/16/

Comment: I like the idea of using setTimeout +1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to contain the menu div inside of the hover div.  See http://jsfiddle.net/T72jm/2/ .

You'll notice (at least in Chrome) that if you hover over your hover div and don't do anything, the menu div will fade out.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these nice examples:

[Nice JQuery menus](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/)

A specific multilevel one:

[Multilevel JQuery menu](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery)

HTML from link 2:

```
    <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3 Javascript</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">3.1 jQuery</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">3.2 Mootools</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.3 Prototype</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 #nav, #nav ul{
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         list-style-type:none;
         list-style-position:outside;
         position:relative;
         line-height:1.5em;
     }

    #nav ul ul{
    top:auto;
    }

#nav li ul ul {
    left:12em;
    margin:0px 0 0 10px;
    }

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
    display:none;
    }
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
    display:block;
    }
```

JS:

```
function mainmenu(){
$(" #nav ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$(" #nav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show(400);
        },function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
        });
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
    mainmenu();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my fix

```
window.menushowing = false;

$('#menu').hover(

function() {
    window.menushowing = true;
}, function() {
    window.menushowing = false;
    hideMenu();
});

function hideMenu() {
    if (window.menushowing) return;
    $('#menu').animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1500, function() {
        $('#menu').hide();
    });
}

$('#examplePic').hover(

function() {
    window.menushowing = true;
    $('#menu').css('display', 'block');
    $('#menu').animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1500);

}, function() {
    hideMenu();
});
```