# css menu with jQuery effects control

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like some help if possible, I have this css menu which I am adding jquery effects like fade etc.

```
$('.main_menu li').hover(function()
{
    $(this).children('ul').hide().fadeIn(300);
},
function()
{
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
});
```

So far things are good except a small detail that I would like to take care of. For example if a user moves the mouse away from a submenu of a submenu in order to return to the first submenu there is always the chance that the mouse pointer will be out of menu range for at least some milliseconds and this just fades out the whole menu. I would like to give it a delay or something before javascript decides to fade the menu out, at the same time that If the mouse just moves from one to another submenu that has submenus, then not have a delay. What is the best way to do this in this particular case ?

Have a great day and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle as well ?

Comment: Using a timeout, or setInterval

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have tried setInterval but I don't know where exactly to put it in the code :)

Comment: Shivan, I will make one yes.

Comment: Try the hoverIntent jQuery plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: you're using jquery , so you can use the `delay` method: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: or take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184988/jquery-menu-hovering

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the fadeout effect with a timeout. Be careful with the 'this' keyword here. You will need to store its context:

```
$('.main_menu li').hover(function()
{
    $(this).children('ul').hide().fadeIn(300);
},
function()
{
    // need to keep the context 
    var that = this;

    // set a 100ms timeout
    setTimeout(function() {
        // if you use this here it would refer to the
        // function in the timeout
        $(that).children('ul').stop(true, true).fadeOut(200);
    }, 100);
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XexmW/